# How can I allocate more SSD space for Ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning, performance, swap, disk-usage

I need more space for my Ubuntu system in my disk. I have a swap memory partition between two spaces that I want to become one. I run Ubuntu on 50 GB (26 GB Free + 24 GB (Blue) Currently running system)

I have to make 50GB for the currently running system and start from the start of the partition.

[image: screenshot of partition scheme]

What is the easiest way to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Answer (score 1):

It is a good idea to **backup** everything, that you cannot afford to lose before continuing, because the following operations are potentially risky.

This is a method, that will not tamper with the head end of the root partition (and the swap partition) to **make a `/home` partition in the unallocated space**. (If you tamper with the head end of the root partition, you must also modify `grub`, the bootloader.)

- Create a partition with an `ext4` file system.
- Copy the content of the current `/home` directory into it for example with `rsync` (first 'dry run' to check, then remove the `n` and do the real copy),

  ```
  sudo rsync -Havn /home/ /mount-point-of-the-new-partition
  ```
- Modify your `/etc/fstab` to make the system use the new partition as `/home`.
- When you see that things are working, you can remove the `/home` directory from the root partition, but watch out (make sure that you are deleting the correct data, and not the 'new home'.

---

You may prefer to do these operations, when booted from another drive, for example a USB boot drive with Ubuntu. In that case the `rsync`command line will be different: Mount the internal drive's root partition and copy from it,

```
sudo rsync -Havn /mount-point-of-internal-drive-root/home/ /mount-point-of-the-new-partition
```